# Segmentation fault while initializing an empty std::vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am trying to use an array of vector like this:

```
vector<foo*> *vec = new vector<foo*>(n);
```

Some positions of vec will be empty and some of them will be later on filled with some data:

```
vec[i].push_back(&foo_var);
```

My problem is the empty positions of vec. Let's say that for `i` equal to `0`, I did not `push_back` anything. Then, when I try to do some check, for example,

```
vec[0].size();
```

instead of the expected return `0`, the program returns a huge number `1457283635`.

Searching around, I found that I should had initialized the empty positions. Then I try this:

```
vector<foo*> vec = new vector<for*>(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    vec[i] = vector<foo*>();
}
...
```

This "solution" was enough to make my program works as I expected (returning `0` as the size of an empty position, for instance).

However, after increasing the size of `n`, my program crashes in this line now:

```
vec[i] = vector<foo*>();
```

The program sends a segmentation fault error.

- Can someone please explain what is happening?
- How should I handle this specific case?
- What are the best practices for vector initialization in this case?

Comment: `new vector<for*>(n);` you have a typo here (in both places where this line appears)

Comment: Why not initializing the _"empty"_ slots with `nullptr`? Also I would seriously recommend using something like `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>>>`.

Comment: @Quest `for` is a keyword, it can't possibly appear as a typename in `vector<for>`

Comment: You're creating a single vector of size `n` instead of `n` vectors.

Comment: `new vector` 99% of the time means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: are you trying to make a lot of vectors or just one. At the moment you mix 2 things together. You create one vector but then do vec[i] which assumes you made a bunch of vectors

Comment: @NeilKirk What you mean? Can you provide a source for me to read.

Comment: The point of vectors is to avoid manual memory management. `vector<foo*> vec(n);`

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but `vec[i].push_back(&foo_var);` is suspicious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
vector<foo*> *vec = new vector<foo*>[n];
```

instead of

```
vector<foo*> *vec = new vector<foo*>(n);
```

The first one allocates indeed an array of vectors in the dynamic memory while the scond one allocates a single vector with n elements.
Take into account that you could define a vector of vectors. For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<foo *>> vec( n );
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is enough to avoid the segmentation fault error. 
Can you explain better why should I do a vector of vectors? As the people commented in my question, should I avoid doing an array of vectors as best practice?

Comment: @MFS Because it is the vector itself that will manage the allocated memory. You need not to bother about deleting or reallocating of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to create `n` empty vectors, or a single vetor filled with `n` elements?

I'm assuming the former but by using `()` in your `new` statement you've actually accomplished the latter, creating but a single vector with `n` `foo*` elements in it.

You should solve this by using a vector of vectors so you don't have to do memory management yourself.

```
std::vector<std::vector<foo*> > vec(n);
```

This then creates `n` empty vectors of `foo*`.

Answer (score 0):

Do your requirements indicate you have to use dynamic memory?

If not, might be simpler to create as:

`vector<foo*> vec;`

Then use vec as a 'regular' vector variable, instead of using a pointer-to-vector?

Then it is simpler(?) to just do:

`vector<foo*> vec;`

`foo* pFoo = something;`

`vec.push_back(pFoo);`